Should this notched jack stud be replaced?
We're remodeling our kitchen and I'm doing all of the rough work (hiring the cabinet installation and tile and backsplash.) I'm getting close to being finished with the electrical and just discovered that someone before me notched out most of the jack stud next to an interior door in what appears to be a load bearing wall.
I need to make the electrical box in this location a two gang box instead of single gang, and I was planning to shift the whole thing away from the door trim since it was installed really close to the door. My intended location would require cutting our most of the king stud, so I'm not going to do that.
I'm thinking I'll move it a little bit further away from the door so that the right side of the box is against the king stud. My question though is whether it's worth cutting both the king and jack out and replacing them so that the jack doesn't have a "notch" going 4/5 the way through the stud.
I think the wall is load bearing because:

Runs down pretty much the middle of the house.
Has a 4x8 header plus (4x6+2x4) in addition to a double top plate.
The roof trusses are resting on it.




Update: I removed a bit more of the plaster (yes, it's really plaster) and here's another picture. There are actually two jack studs for whatever that's worth. One of them only has about 1/2 notched out on side.


that middle stud looks like its a conglomerate of 2x4s. Ignoring the notched hole I see 4 2x4 pieces stacked on top of each other (maybe others lower). What this means exactly and how to approach I'm not sure, but even without the notch it has issues

Jack studs hold up headers.  Kind of important they are complete in a load bearing wall.  You only have a few nails now holding the header up now.  Thinking where you can move that box, will be good.

If the roof structure is trusses, they normally transfer all their load to the outside walls. If the bottom chord happens to touch a wall in the middle of the house, that does not make the wall load bearing. If you are using the term trusses imprecisely, it might be a bearing wall. If the trusses are highly unusual, it might be a bearing wall.

@Ecnerwal they aren't engineered trusses, so I'm probably not using the colloquial definition.

I'm not an engineer, but it looks like the notched studs are part of 4 studs. There should be an interior jack to the right of the notched 2.  It should be totally intact.
Everything there has withstood the test of time. You said the roof trusses sit on the wall, so you don't have an upper floor. You did not mention the door binding or any signs that the header is dipping.  So there is no issues there.
If it makes you feel more secure, you can cut a block to put in the notch and add a plate on the outside.  If you are very ambitious, tear out the notched studs and replace them. (I think that is not needed.)

Yea I'd say cut it out a little more to clear it up,  wedge/jam and shim a section of 4x4  in there and plate it.
